# html select smaller than html input in ie6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, yaml

I am having some issues with one of my html forms. It looks like because the select drop downs and the input text boxes are not the same size all my controls are misaligned in ie6. You can see that all the controls under selected date get pushed out of alignment more and more as we go down. This does not happen in firefox.

[image]

I am using yaml as my css framework and I thought that it would be covered but it doesn't seem to be. Can someone please give me an idea on how to make the controls the same size or give ma an idea on an alternative fix.

I've put the html for the form here.... http://pastebin.com/cVrVadQf

thanks

Comment: Is it really important to have a perfect-looking design (or a working site fwiw) in IE6?!

Comment: IE6 (and the fact developers still decide to support it) is why we can't have nice things

Comment: IE6 died with windows xp, i see no reason to have it supported. When the only problem is how something looks, don't waste your time fixing this, as long as it is functional. When we don't stop supporting software that is 13 years old, when will be able to use the full potential of new technology? I understand this can be required by customers. But developers have an responsibility to educate their customers on this topic. Usually it works best to show them which Browsers google does Support for their products

Comment: check the css for the heading. if you are using `Heading elements` then give minimal width

Comment: Unfortunately I'm constrained by my corporate environment. And yes. We use ie6.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is caused by a mis-match in inputs and select sizes.  The two "Exception type" selectors seem out of line too. Looks like it might be a clearing issue, but without seeing the CSS that goes with form, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess I'll have to find a way. I posted this as I was interested particularly from anyone who knows yaml css to see if they had the same problem or if I was doing anything wrong. I'll have more of a play and see what I can figure out

Comment: @Richie _"And yes. We use ie6."_ — Get out. Now. While you still can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I just piggy backed onto yaml conditional css foe ie6. I added my own stylesheet as you can see below...

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link href="resources/css/custom-myer-ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="resources/css/yaml/yaml/core/iehacks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Then added some simple styling to make sure alignment was ok...

```
.ym-form .ym-fbox-select select#businessDateFilterType, 
.ym-form .ym-fbox-select select#exceptionFilterType {
    margin:2px !important;
}

.ym-form .ym-fbox-select select#registerFilterType,
.ym-form .ym-fbox-select select#teamMemberFilterType {
    margin:4px !important;
}

.ym-form fieldset.border {
    border: none !important;
}
```